# Alternative to MR_findFirstWithPredicate that doesn't block main thread?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Doing simple fetches with MR like this:

```
    Cat* cat = [Cat MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Time Profiler is flagging this as one of the most time-sucking processes in my app. And in fact the stack trace for MR_findFirstWithPredicate leads to this:

```
+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSError *error = nil;

        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (results == nil) 
        {
            [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
        }

    }];
    return results; 
}
```

Note the "performBlockAndWait", which is the root of the problem. So what's the alternative? How can I perform fetches in the background?

Comment: Did you read Apple's docs on this subject as I posted a few days ago on a very similar question from you?

Comment: Magical Record is a 3rd party library and is not covered in Apple's docs.

Comment: You don't have to do everything with MR. And it wouldn't hurt to read the docs from Apple to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Performing the find in a managed object context on a non-main thread will prevent the main thread being blocked:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
[backgroundContext performBlock:^{
    Cat* cat = [Cat MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:backgroundContext];
}];
```

As suggested by Koen above, this is not a MagicalRecord concept — it's a key part of Core Data. Whilst MagicalRecord can make some things in Core Data a little simpler, it would greatly benefit you to understand how/why Core Data works as well.

Comment: That method also appears to call `performBlockAndWait:`, so I think that's the same behavior as the asker's original snippet.

Comment: Good catch — I've wrapped the find in a call to the context's `-performBlock:` which should cause the subsequent `-performBlockAndWait:` to wait on the context's queue, not the main queue.